# Obtener array de un tabla sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

oigan quería preguntartes como obtener individualmente los objetos de un tabla de sqlite, escencialmente necesito obtener la fecha de esta cita para compararla con la fecha actual, pero tengo problemas para hacer el fetch de estos datos ... 
lo que realmente me interesa es obtener fecha y hora en alguna variable
Gracias

```js
var citas = memberDatabase.GetCitas();
int citCount = citas.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < citCount; i++) {

  var ct = new Cita();

  ct = citas[i];

  /*Supongo que debe ser algo como
    IEnumerable<Cita> ct = citas;
    ct = citas[i];
    var dt = ct.fecha[i]
    ...
    Pues aquí me falta algo de code*/


}
```

Esta es mi clase y mi método GetCitas

```js
public IEnumerable < Cita > GetCitas() {
  var citasx = (from cit in conn.Table < Cita > () select cit);
  return citasx.ToList();
}

// Clase Cita

{
  [PrimaryKey]
  public int ID {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string razon {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string descripcion {
    set;
    get;
  }
  public string fecha {
    set;
    get;
  }
  public string hora {
    set;
    get;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listow :3

```js
List < Cita > citas = memberDatabase.GetCitasL();
int citCount = citas.Count();
foreach(Cita ct in citas) {
  var dt = ct.fecha;
}
```